# hide shortcuts bar when hide keyboard ios(Ipad)

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

Shortcut bar is not hidden when hide the keyboard by clicking **keyboard** icon in the bottom-right of the keyboard,and  can not trigger `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`.

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“it is showing only in simulator if try on device it will hide shortcuts also hide on device. – johny kumar 
”

Answer (score 3):

As of iOS 9 beta 2, the documentation is still very thin on the ground (and vaguely misleading) but I've had success using this UITextFieldDelegate method implementation.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField  
{  
    UITextInputAssistantItem* item = [textField inputAssistantItem];  
    item.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[];  
    item.trailingBarButtonGroups = @[];  
}
```

Comment: yeah,the solution can hide the shortcuts ,but I want to keep shortcuts when editing ,and hide the shortcuts when hide the keyboard

Comment: it is showing only in simulator if you try on device it will hide shortcuts also try on device.

Comment: @Johny kumar is right, it is showing only in simulator. Apple kill me two hours lift :-D

Comment: johny kumar's answer is right, how to accept... @Maulik

Comment: @Leo not an issue,your problem is resolved he spent his time for solution accept his answer that will help others also when they face this issue,you can upvote my comment.@Maulik please update your answer according to his comments.

Comment: @leo get only answers..not give any points...when he can't give any points..i minus this question...

Comment: I appreciate @Maulik's spent his time for the solution, but the title of  my question is how to hide the shortcut  when hide keyboard, and the Maulik's answer is that how to hide the shortcut normally. I know the right answer is in these comments, and I do not want to make others confused,so  not accept the answer. It is better that Maulik can update the answer to make it more clear. :-D